# Unable to install crontab on OpenSuse

Tags: linux, cron, opensuse

I am running the following command as root, on OpenSuse:

```
linux-gn77-PC:/home/harbir/project # crontab -e
```

when the editor opens up I type the following, as I want the command to be run at 2145 hours

```
45 21 * * * * /home/harbir/project/maildispatcher.sh  &> /tmp/mycommand.log
```

when I try to save the file, I get the following message

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.WOxjzG":1: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

I want the output of the crontab to go the file `/tmp/mycommand.log`.

Answer (score 10):

You have one field too many in the crontab line.

It should be

```
minute hour dayofmonth month dayofweek command
```

You have an asterisk character in place of the command.

Also, if you want a crontab entry to run as root, it's arguably cleaner to put it in a /etc/cron.d/ file than in root's own user-level crontab.

Note that system crontabs (i.e. /etc/cron*) have a subtly different format. There is an extra field after the dayofweek field that contains the name of the user to run the command as.

Comment: Thanks! I originally found the format at http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm, and without careful reading, one could assume the format specifies 6 time columns, but standard crontabs have just 5.